# Identity Server 3 issue with logging out - log out doesn't work

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, identityserver3

I have an issue, with little complex architecture.
Here is architecture with my magical mspaint skills:
[image: architecture]

Legend:

- Client1 - application that can trigger log in and log out to SSO(box
  on the most top)

  - SSO - it is sso which accepts wsfed and returns response in saml to the bridge
  - Bridge is an intermediate SSO, because the client2 is net core app, and net core didn't support identity server(owin) of SSO(box on the
    most top) at that time, so we had to put intermediate bridge app to
    take care for request. This app uses UseWsFederationAuthentication to
    authenticate towards SSO.
  - Client 2 authenticates on SSO, then SSO sends authorizationresponse to Bridge, and if everything ok, client 2 is logged in.

Problem appears that when I log out from Client 1, it doesn't log out client 2. What am I missing? If you need code I can put all together, but out of head is this architecture supported?

SSO(wsfed) and Bridge SSO(calling wsfed SSO) in the middle and then client?

I enabled logging with SeriLog and when **endsessioncallback** is made sid parameter is empty:
core/connect/endsessioncallback?sid=

Error:

> w3wp.exe Information: 0 : 2017-02-15 12:22:36.418 +00:00 [Information] End session callback requested
>   2017-02-15 12:22:36.433 +00:00 [Debug] No client end session iframe URLs
>
> 2017-02-15 12:22:36.386 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-15T12:22:36.3867557Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Web.Http.ModelBinding', Id=00000000-0000-0000-c044-0080000000ea, Operation=HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
>   2017-02-15 12:22:36.386 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-15T12:22:36.3867557Z] Level=Info, Kind=Begin, Category='System.Web.Http.ModelBinding', Id=00000000-0000-0000-c044-0080000000ea, Message='Binding parameter 'sid'', Operation=ModelBinderParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
>   2017-02-15 12:22:36.403 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-15T12:22:36.4035482Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Web.Http.ModelBinding', Id=00000000-0000-0000-c044-0080000000ea, ***Message='Model state is invalid. sid.String: A value is required but was not present in the request.',*** Operation=ModelBinderParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
>   2017-02-15 12:22:36.403 +00:00 [Debug] [2017-02-15T12:22:36.4035482Z] Level=Info, Kind=End, Category='System.Web.Http.ModelBinding', Id=00000000-0000-0000-c044-0080000000ea, Message='Model state is invalid. sid.String: A value is required but was not present in the request.', Operation=HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync

What could be the cause that sid is not provided and could that be the case?